# After publishing web app to Azure, all the redirect rules in web.config get wiped out

Tags: azure, redirect, asp.net-core, web-config

My asp net core project does not have a web.config file, so what I do after publishing is to go into 'Server Explorer' toolbar and manually open & edit the remote web.config to re-add the redirect rules.  All works great until I publish again to update the app.  Then I have to go through the manual steps again to paste my redirect rules back in.  So in short, every publish seems to transform the remote web.config back to bare bones.

Is there a better way around this?  I've already tried making a local version of web.config with all the redirects inside, but it seems that publishing completely ignores it.

Thanks!

Comment: You could exclude the web.config from the publish. See https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7727. However, as has been pointed out, middleware can be used for the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect middleware to perform redirections. Check
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Comment: Thank you but I feel that Azure team should make a fix for this.  For example, if a system administrator needs to update web.config rules in Azure, he can do it without having to have the app developer make changes to the app itself.  Plus, I'd like for IIS to do this work so the app can use its precious resources to take care of other well formed requests.

Comment: usually the changes should be there that you are making to the web.config are you sure you are not updating it any where ?